# iOS search engine app with “save domain” feature

Tags: ios, search-engine

I want an iOS app where you search in a search engine and collect results.

**Description:**

- Not a full-featured browser
- Exactly like the Google app except it can save web domains

  - If I see a website such as “`www.powertools.com/thehammer`”, I can select `Save Domain` to save the website `www.powertools.com`

**Purpose:**

I prefer the focus of a search engine app. I want to save and organize websites for later consumption.